# Send iframe to back on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building this webpage that has a popup div (with javascript/jquery) to show some text, but I keep having a problem. Behind this popup, there is a youtube embedded video (iframe) that on Internet Explorer only, stays in front of the pop up. I have tried using z-index property to fix it but nothing. On Chrome it works perfectly but IE ruins it. I have some alternatives, like fadding it out with the popup or setting its display to "none" but it doesn't look very good....
Any thoughts on how to send it to the back?

Tanks to you all, 
cheers.

Comment: if you want to put flash behind html you gonna have problem

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Its an iframe not flash.

Comment: It is an easy fix, the duplicated I posted shows you how to disable it with the querystring.

Comment: @Sam i believe there is flash video in inframe

Comment: @epascarello It worked. I had been around this for a long time. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your iframe url `&wmode=opaque`

Alternatively try `?wmode=transparent`

Explanation:
http://www.scorchsoft.com/news/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix

Comment: The first one solved it, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Have you set zoom:1 in your CSS? IE requires zoom to be set for z-index.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the CSS. It has to due with a setting on the flash player.

Comment: agreed...but he'd still have to set Zoom:1 for IE